# How to redirect to a page automatically if a value returns true on each pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I connect to my site I arrive on a default home page via `react-router`.

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/home" />
  {routes.map((route, index) => (
    <PrivateRoute
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      component={route.component}
    />
  ))}
  <Route path="/unauthorized" component={NotAuthenticated} />
  <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage} />
</Switch>
```

I call a service that returns me a boolean `true/false` value.

I would like that when this value returns `false` I be redirected to another page automatically.

I tried this solution :

```
{withoutAccess ? (
  <Redirect
    exact={true}
    from="/"
    to="/anotherPage"
  />
) : (
  <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/home" />
)}
```

If `withoutAccess` returns `true` then I am redirected to `anotherPage` otherwise to `home`.

It works pretty well but when I change pages the redirection no longer happens.

Is there a solution that would cause me to be redirected at each page change if the value returns `true`.

Comment: What "value" are you referring to that returns `true`? Do you have some logic that is running each time when the URL path changes? Please include all relevant code you are trying to work with and use in the post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, the redirect only occurs if the user is *exactly* on the `"/"` path.

Comment: the value true is called once on the react-router which allows the change of page, in fact I would have to find the place which makes it possible to check this value each time to send perhaps a history push

Comment: What is `PrivateRoute` component doing? I'm sure it is running some logic each time the path is changed and it's possibly a matched route (*to either redirect to a login path or render a route with the protected content*). This is a hint that maybe the `withoutAccess` should be a similar implementation. Like I said though, the redirect is only happening if the user is on the `"/"` path, so it's already sort of ignoring path changes.

Comment: it's not fake i'm watching this